# When does festival of the lost end?

Tags: destiny

In Destiny, when does The Festival of The Lost end? I have looked on other websites to find this but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I was wondering if anyone on here knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The festival of the lost ends at the next weekly reset, Tuesday, November 9th, at 9:00 AM UTC.

[Source](https://www.bungie.net/en/pub/festivalofthelost)

Comment: Yes, that's what the weekly update from the 29th said (the one which announced the festival).